# Android Library Design/Configuration

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have the following situation and I don't really know how to solve it. We have a **library module** that we use **in our app** but we **also** release this library to **end customers**. The problem is that the library shouldn't include all files and all methods in both cases.

So imagine the following case:

- class A with methods A::a1(), A::a2()
- class B with methods B::b1(), B::b2()
- class C with methods C::c1(), C::c2()

I would like to have now the following result:

- in case of our app - the library should include all classes with all methods
- in case of the end customers - I'd like e.g. to **remove class C** and **remove method B::b2()** from the library

How would I achieve this on Android? On iOS this is a rather easy problem since you can just define different header files for different configurations. In that case the implementation file can include all methods etc. and you just configure everything with the corresponding header files.

I hope somebody can help me! :)

Comment: See if you can extract methods and classes you need and put'em in a library that you made.

Comment: In my example classes A, B and C are already in the library. But in the second case class C shouldn't be included and method b2() of class B should be excluded as well. I'm trying to find a way how to configure my project to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: There's no such way to cut the library to peaces. If it's open source then you can separate things you need from it and build a new library.

Comment: I know that I can use different productFlavours and adjust the sourceSets for the different flavours (like excluding files) but I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Therefore my question. But I don't have any idea how to handle the different methods of the different classes.

Comment: I'm not sure but by activating proguard in you project useless methods will be handled automatically.
I suggest you take a look at use of proguard.

Comment: ok, I'll have  a look at it. But I'm not sure if it will work the way how I'm imagining it. Because I would like to work with productFlavours (let's say there are 2, one for the app and one for the library only). If I select the library only and build also just the library module, then there would be no calls to any methods at all. So all methods would be removed?!